# Adonis.js: Как получить ширину и высоту загруженной на сервер картинки?

Tags: node.js, upload

Необходимо перед сохранением изображения проверить ширину и высоту на попадания в допустимые диапазоны. Но вот беда, на сервере объект `upload` выглядит как-то вот так:

[image: upload]

То есть здесь только общие для всех файлов свойства. А мне нужно достучаться до свойств изображения, в частности размеров. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это делается в Adonis.js или хотя бы на любом другом Node.js фреймворке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как можно было догадаться, upload ничего не может знать о ширине и высоте изображения. Для решения этой задачи был задействован сторонний пакет Jimp, который понимает немало форматов изображения и может изъять из них необходимые мне метрики.